# How can we manually enter a payment using their credit card information for a customer in Commerce?

Tags: commerce

We have customers that are not web savvy and would like us to enter their order for them on the website.

Currently, the admin masquerades as the user, creates the order as them, checks out as them, and then enters their credit card info. Then un-masquerades.

Is there an easier way to do this? We've tried Creating an Order in the backend but the Payments tab says the following for all Credit Card payment methods.

```
"There are no reusable payment methods available for the selected gateway."
```

We were hoping it would be as easy as manually creating the order and then enter the payment for Commerce does not seem to allow enter CC info on the backend.

***We're using Authorize.net***

Answer (score 1):

- Create the order in the admin UI and add the user as the first step of creating the order.
- Save the order.
- Go to People and then edit the user you just created.  Add payment info.
- Then add shipping info in the orders > shipments tab (if you have a shippable product).
- Then go to Orders > Payments and you should be able to add the payment that you just added and make the charge (if cc).
- Then edit the order and place the order.

Maybe there is an easier way to do this but so far these are the bizarre steps I am going through.

Comment: Thank you. We'll try this this week but it sounds like it will work. We were missing the adding the payment info to the person step.

Comment: @quantumized I spoke a bit too soon. My steps work with the example CC payment method if you installed commerce demo plugin. With Stripe payment method you can add payment method to the user's account and then go back in to the order in the admin UI.  You won't get the no reuseable payments error and will be able to select the user's cc.  However, when you go to authorize, it will throw an error. 
 Basically still an issue but there is a patch supposedly to resolve. 
 You can view here for more info: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe/issues/3195527

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the info!